# I want to edit corresponding postgresql data of a vector from openlayers- how to do it?

Tags: gis, postgis, openlayers

I want to edit the corresponding text/numeric data type columns of a vector through openlayres, when a user click/mouse over a vector. like,

http://dev4.mapgears.com/bdga/bdgaWFS-T.html#

any tutorial page for how to do it?
I gone through it ,
it was difficult for me to understand from its js codes.

-posted in gis.stackexchange

Comment: I suggest to move this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In the example, OpenLayers is getting data from a WFS server with a Postgres/PostGIS backend.
You could try [FeatureServer](http://featureserver.org/), but the [GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place to ask for help on this.